# Get information about schema, tables, primary keys

Tags: db2, db2-luw

How to get the name of the schema, tables and primary keys?
How to know his authorizations?
The only information I have is obtained by the command below:

```
db2 => connect

   Database Connection Information

 Database server        = DB2/AIX64 11.1.3.3
 SQL authorization ID   = mkrugger
 Local database alias   = DBRCF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command line (interactive command line processor), if you want, but if you are starting out then it is easier to use a GUI tool.

Example free GUI, [IBM Data Studio](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037681), and there are many more (any GUI that works with JDBC should work with Db2 on Linux/Unix/Windows). These are easy to find online and download if you are permitted.

To use the Db2 command-line (clp) which is what you show in your question, 
Example command lines:

```
list tables for all
list tables for user
list tables for schema ...
describe table ...
describe indexes for table ...
```

Reference for [LIST TABLES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001967.html) command
You can also use plain SQL to read the catalog views, which describes the schemas, tables, primary keys as a series of views.

Look in the online free [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html) for details of views like SYSCAT.TABLES,  SYSCAT.COLUMNS , SYSCAT.INDEXES  and hundreds of other views.

Depending on which Db2 product is installed locally, there are a range of other command-line based tools. One in particular is `db2look` which lets you extract all of the DDL of the database (or a subset of it) into a plain text file if you prefer that.

Comment: Warmly thanks a lot, I am going to check as quickly as possible, then accept your answer.